# Why I need to import server certificates in java

Tags: java, ssl

We have developed an console application which will bring data from ESB (https://esb.mkcl.org/) which is on HTTPS. When I hit to this web site I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated` exception. I changed URL to https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/ which is also on HTTPS and after giving hit I have NOT received any exception.

After some searching I come to know that I have to import public certificate in java's keystore i.e cacerts (C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security). So I exported certificate of  https://esb.mkcl.org/ from browser and imported in java using `keytool` and then executed console application and it works!! no exception is occurred.

So the question is why I need to import certificate for that *particulate* URL (where as other HTTPS URLs are working without importing any certificate in java)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root certificate used by that server's certificate (COMODO RSA Certification Authority) was [added](https://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml) to Java in Java 8 Update 51, so that means the java version you're using (java6 from your jre path) is too old to already include it.

To have that certificate trusted by default, update to a never java version.

And by the way, the ssl configuration for [that server](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=https%3A%2F%2Fesb.mkcl.org%2F) is pretty insecure.

Comment: I got it about why I need to import certificate into java and about ssl configuration I told to my IT infra team but they are saying all config in glassfish is perfect!! I don't know how they are saying it. Thanks for evidence. If you have any idea about which config is not "perfect" then please guide.

Comment: Well, the issues listed in the ssllabs test page are explained in detail there. If you look at the second trust path you see that it requires an additional download of a [version](http://crt.comodoca.com/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt) of the above mentioned root certificate cross signed by the AddTrust External Root CA (which should be in the trust store). Java doesn't do that download automatically, so for that turst path to be taken the server would also need to send that certificate, and then it would work for older clients.

Answer (score 2):

A client-side SSL implementation relies on a set of known "trusted root certificates".  These are certificates for SSL Certification Authorities that are known to be trusted / trustworthy.

The "problem" is that the set of trusted certs in the keystore that is distributed in your Java JDK / JRE is (typically) smaller than the set in a typical web browser.

There are reasons for this.  For example:

- A "server" Java installation probably needs to be more conservative on who to trust by default ... for security reasons.
- You may be running an older (i.e. out of maintenance) version of Java.  Obviously, Oracle will not be refreshing the keystore with new trusted certs.

Some JREs can make use of either the host OSes default keystore, or a browser keystore.

- Access to the Mac OS X keystore was introduced in [Java 7u4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html).
- Browser plugins can use the [browser keystore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/keystores.html).